# Android: How to remove Jelly Bean gray bar on notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean, notification-bar

Is there a way to remove the gray bar on static notification created by Jelly Bean?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

tap the little stack button onthe bar next to the clock and it will hide all the notifications. worked on my xoom.